# BigQuery Performance

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any way to stabilize the response time of queries? For example, this two jobs that execute the same query, have different response times:

> JobId: job_gzTkFvGculpLw0tQRMZvj6rskMI Query Time: 00:00:09.2827336
>
> JobId: job_9wXD9ONxDoI87lD6lOXZJSEM1aE Query Time: 00:00:28.1064037

Why does the same query take very different response times?

**EDIT: The projectId is nostrum.eu:nostrum

Comment: FYI: If you post a project id along with a job id it is easier for a bigquery engineer to look up what happened in the logs.

Comment: The projectId is nostrum.eu:nostrum

Comment: Now, this jobId job_KsGKrJuoE9_LvuDBKNnIZnaZn5s has taken more than one minute to response.

Comment: FYI I looked into these jobs and this does not seem to be expected behavior. I'll respond with a more complete answer after further diagnosis.

Comment: @JordanTigani it's not related to this, but also check this support request (ref is mentioned), Mario looks like cannot handle it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792224/backend-error-received-while-some-calls-were-success

Answer (score 2):

By default, BigQuery uses [Query caching](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#querycaching) to speed up response times for common queries that may be used multiple times.

This is important to remember if you are loading or streaming data constantly into the database, because your cached query results may not be the most up to date results for the query.

If you want to disable query caching, you can set the parameter in the query body that you send to the API:

```
{
  "kind": "bigquery#queryRequest",
  "query": query,
  "defaultDataset": {
    "datasetId": string,
    "projectId": string
  },
  "useQueryCache": False
}
```

This should make it so that your repeat requests of the same query will have relatively the same response time, but you will be billed for each query request, as opposed to being billed for just the one request that it takes to cache the results.

Comment: Note that BigQuery caches become automatically invalidated every time the underlying table changes, so no stale data should be served.

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery users execute their queries in shared infrastructure. The benefit is substantially low querying prices (without having to pay hourly prices), but execution times become variable depending on how many concurrent queries from other users are executing at the same time (that's why BQ enforces concurrent queries quota limits for each user).

If consistency is required, BigQuery also offers an exclusive infrastructure mode to customers, where only their queries run on machines dedicated exclusively to them. However, these machines need to be reserved on a monthly basis. As an additional benefit, these customers are not subjected to concurrent queries quotas, since it's their own space to play anyways.

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/pricing#reserved_cap

Comment: We've contacted with commercial service for contract this infrastructure. The commercial service said that we create a virtual machine, but how does using BigQuery from the virtual machine? Could you give more details about this?

Comment: Weird. Do you have more details I can use to investigate?

Comment: as you recommend, we contacted the customer services, but they didn't know anything about an exclusive infrastructure mode for BigQuery, they told about virtual machines, but we think that you were not referring to virtual machines. How can we contract this exclusive service?

Comment: Sorry for not noticing this reply earlier. Who did you talk to? Where did you find their contact? I'm wondering if you talked to Google or a 3d party integrator.

Comment: Hi Felipe, the link you posted doesnt mention 'reserved capacity' anymore.  I can only find a glimpse of it in the search results, but the page it links to[1], no longer has the text either.
[1]: https://cloud.google.com/s/results?q=reserved+capacity&p=%2Fbigquery