# Ingest csv file times in BQ

Tags: csv, google-bigquery

In doing tests with ingesting files directly from GCS to bigquery, we get much better performance over streaming inserts. However, the performance also fluctuates much more,

For example, we tested loading large CSV into BQ (10M rows, 2GB): loaded in 2.275 min the first time but ~ 8 minutes the second time. Why is there such a fluctuation in the import times?

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load

---

**Update**: This turned out to be a change in a threshold value:

Turned out it depends on `MaxError` property. The time I got CSV imported in 2 min was when MaxError too low and some errors (like too long fields) prevented it for parsing CSV file fully. I have raised MaxError to 1000 since.

Tried couple of times, and it takes 7-8 minutes to complete parsing with this threshold value set.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that you pay for streaming. You don't with batch loading. Is there any specific reason why you need fast ingestion times from GCS?

Comment: @GrahamPolley yes, we have very large files, and are ingesting them all the time. `Difference in performance on 10M csv file: streaming inserts: 13-14m
load from GCS: 7-8m`

Comment: We batch load about 20TB per day from GCS. Times fluctuate because it's a shared resource/cluster (as described by Hua in his answer). Due to its architecture, BigQuery is a non-deterministic application i.e. it will never give you the same query/load times.

Comment: @GrahamPolley thanks -- do you do anything with Progress bars to know the statuses on these? I'm curious how to do this, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43104246/how-to-get-progress-on-bq-file-load.

Comment: We don't use progress bars. We just track the state i.e. whether they are "RUNNING", "PENDING" etc. We don't care how long they take. We simply have asyc batch apps running all these loads jobs and then alerting if the job fails for any reason. I also cannot see how to get the job statistics back from the API when the job is running so I don't think it's possible to have any type of progress bar. I tested and had a look at the output, and , like you said, they only show up when it's finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load is basically a query on federated data sources, with the results saved to the destination table. Performance of a query is dependent on the load of the backend system. Felipe explains this well in [BigQuery Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847532/bigquery-performance).